# React Native: Google Nearby API with Exchange Data

Tags: android, react-native, bluetooth, google-nearby

I am trying to use the *Google Nearby API* with *React Native*.

I found the following library: [react-native-nearby-api](https://github.com/badfeatures/react-native-nearby-api)

I would like to make two smartphones sending/receiving data using the [Exchange Data](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/android/exchange-data) part of the Google Nearby specifications but in the project I didn't found some API that can do that.

Looking at the code, I checked that with the React Native Nearby API you can only broadcast data while I would like to have the following:

- Discover another smartphone close to me (and I can do that with [Exchange Data](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/android/exchange-data))
- Sending and receiving some private messages between the 2 smartphones

Do you know if I am missing something to make this possible or if there is another React Native project that can do that? (I searched but I didn't find anything :( )

Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0):

The library you're linking to only implemented [Nearby Messages](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/overview).

You're going to want to use a library that implements [Nearby Connections](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/overview) like [react-native-google-nearby-connections](https://github.com/butchmarshall/react-native-google-nearby-connection)

Disclaimer: I'm developing that library.